# Cordova / Android. Disable Submit on Keyboard Enter Key

Tags: javascript

I want to disable the Form being submitted when the Enter Key is pressed.

How can I achieve this. Been searching for a solution for a while now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
function hideKeyboard(){
    $(document.activeElement).blur();
    return false;
}

<form onsubmit="hideKeyboard()">
    <input type="image" src="views/images/trans.gif"/>
```